# Basic issue with jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I am using a jQuery Accordion for my sidebar navigation. Currently I have 2 links which both have 'children' beneath them.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Eh8C/

You'll notice that when you click 'About Us', the Gallery closes. This shouldn't happen. Gallery should only close when I click 'Gallery'.

How do I fix this?

**Here is my jQuery:**

```
jQuery(function($) {

        $('#accordion > li > a').click(function (e) {
            if ($(this).next('ul').length == 0) {
                // link is for navigation, do not set up accordion here
                return;
            }

            // link is for accordion pane

            //remove all the "Over" class, so that the arrow reset to default
            $('#accordion > li > a').not(this).each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('rel')!='') {
                    $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('rel') + 'Over');
                }

                $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp("slow");
            });

            //showhide the selected submenu
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle("slow");

            //addremove Over class, so that the arrow pointing downup
            $(this).toggleClass($(this).attr('rel') + 'Over');
            e.preventDefault();
        });     

        $('.slides_item').children('div').css('background','#ededed')

    });
```

Many thanks for any pointers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to remove one line:

```
$('#accordion > li > a').not(this).each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('rel')!='') {
        $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('rel') + 'Over');
    }

    // Remove this line, you don't want to slide up other uls.
    // $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp("slow");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6Eh8C/1/

Comment: Wow. I really should have seen that. Many thanks for such a speedy reply.

Comment: That worked perfectly - many thanks. Will accept answer in 5 minutes :)